# Choose a suitable version of Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

I need to choose a suitable version of Ubuntu Where the computer is very fast.

My computer information:

```
Processor Intel Pentium 4 3.00ghz (2CBU)
2046MB RAM
```

Which version is available to me 12.4 or 12.10?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is on-topic here, thanks!

Comment: Plus we can not decide for you if this is all you give us. Either will work and both are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can install the latest version of Ubuntu, but use a different desktop enviorment beside the default (unity). there are lots of great desktop enviorments like [xfce](http://www.xfce.org/), which are faster, and functional.